# Unity Build Errors(IOException: Win32 IO returned 395)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I made a small game to test my skill and hit a road block at the end, when I build it with the x86 architecture I get the following error:

IOException: Win32 IO returned 395. Path: C:\Users\jorde\OneDrive\Desktop\Code stuff\2020.3.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WindowsStandaloneSupport\Variations\win32_nondevelopment_mono\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.AIModule.dll" or "Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.AIModule.dll
System.IO.File.Copy (System.String sourceFileName, System.String destFileName, System.Boolean overwrite) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
UnityEditor.FileUtil.UnityFileCopy (System.String from, System.String to, System.Boolean overwrite) (at <5ad584e208e14caaa9e6b2e6027e9204>:0)
UnityEditor.FileUtil.CopyDirectoryFiltered (System.String source, System.String target, System.Boolean overwrite, System.Func`2[T,TResult] includeCallback, System.Boolean recursive) (at <5ad584e208e14caaa9e6b2e6027e9204>:0) UnityEditor.FileUtil.CopyDirectoryFiltered (System.String source, System.String target, System.Boolean overwrite, System.Func`2[T,TResult] includeCallback, System.Boolean recursive) (at <5ad584e208e14caaa9e6b2e6027e9204>:0)
UnityEditor.WindowsStandalone.WindowsDesktopStandalonePostProcessor.CopyVariationFolderIntoStagingArea (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[T] filesToNotOverwrite) (at <161e4c4538af4ce89288d3ac9704c0e2>:0) DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.SetupStagingArea (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[T] filesToNotOverwrite) (at <5ad584e208e14caaa9e6b2e6027e9204>:0)
DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at <5ad584e208e14caaa9e6b2e6027e9204>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at <5ad584e208e14caaa9e6b2e6027e9204>:0)
UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <5ad584e208e14caaa9e6b2e6027e9204>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <5ad584e208e14caaa9e6b2e6027e9204>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

I have no clue what any of this means and cant find any solutions on youtube or google so I turn to you, mind you, when I build with x86_64 it works but things that were working before the build no longer work. Can anyone help me figure this out?

I just need to know what to google to fix this and /or how to fix this.

Comment: This most likely is a Windows/Unity problem. For the best help I recommend you to head over to the [Unity forums](https://forum.unity.com/), where the Unity devs are to help you!

Comment: thanks, ill give there a shot.

Comment: Welp I havent gotten any help over there so if anyone has any ideas please tell me.